# Stuck at emitting an event in Solidity

Tags: solidity, contract-development, remix

I am stuck at Step-6 of Bitdegree's Solidity tutorial. Question is to Emit an event ScoreChanged with two arguments: int amount (equal to the value that was sent) and bool direction (true for up function and false for down).

This is my solution for this,I have previously checked it with remix and there are no errors in my code. I am able to pass second test case where I have to write bool direction event but stuck at int amount event.I am not able to figure out why my solution is not getting accepted? I hope someone can help me. I am beginner in Solidity.

```
pragma solidity 0.4.17;
contract TugOfWar {

    int public score = 0;
    int constant endAt = 1 ether;
    bool public gameOver = false;
    bool public _direction;
    /*I even tried this
    event ScoreChanged(int indexed _amount, bool indexed _direction);*/
    event ScoreChanged(int _amount, bool _direction);
    event GameEnded(bool _gameOver);

    function up() external payable {
        require(msg.value > 0);
        require(!gameOver);

        int value = int(msg.value);
        score += value;

         ScoreChanged(value,true);

        checkIfGameOver();
    }

    function down() external payable {
        require(msg.value > 0);
        require(!gameOver);

        int value = int(msg.value);
        score -= value;

         ScoreChanged(value,false);

        checkIfGameOver();
    }

    function checkIfGameOver() internal {
        if(score >= endAt || score <= endAt * -1) {
            gameOver = true;
             GameEnded(gameOver);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the problem / what's your question?

Comment: I am not able to figure out why my solution is not getting accepted?

Comment: Is there a test case you have to pass? Do you know what that test is doing? Your code definitely emits an event.

Comment: Perhaps if you shared the text of what you're supposed to do, somebody might be able to spot the issue.

Comment: No there is no as such test case which I need to pass. These is the exact text what is written over there: 'Emit an event ScoreChanged with two arguments: int amount (equal to the value that was sent) and bool direction (true for up function and false for down)'

Answer (score 1):

I just zipped through to lesson six. The second task is:

> Emit an event `ScoreChanged` with two arguments: `int amount` (equal to the value that was sent) and `bool direction` (true for up function and false for down)

Your parameters are incorrectly named. Rename them to match:

```
event ScoreChanged(int amount, bool direction);
```

Comment: I am able to pass the second task with my code. The problem lies in the 1st task. I hope you can help me out.

Comment: Your existing code looks correct for the first task.

Comment: Oh, sorry, your parameters are incorrectly named.

Comment: Yep, there is no error but I am not able to pass it and according to their policy, I can't proceed to next chapter until I have successfully submitted previous programming exercises.

Comment: OMG !! Changing parameters' name helped but one can name them anything, correct?

Comment: Yes. But whatever checking they're doing to make sure you accomplished the task is apparently not flexible enough to handle that.

Comment: I went through the entire course just now, and my general impression is that it's bad. Lots of little issues in their prose, code, and testing.

Comment: Yeah, I completely agree with you. Can you please suggest me some other quality resources?

Comment: I know https://cryptozombies.io/ is quite popular, but I haven't gone through it myself.

Comment: Okay, I will surely try that too. Thank you so much.

Comment: I'm going through CryptoZombies now, and I think it may be worse in terms of pickiness about (often wrong) details. They seem to just diff your code against their desired solution.

Comment: Damn, Is there anything on earth from where a beginner could learn? lol

Answer (score 0):

here is the correct code.

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.17;

contract TugOfWar {

    int public score = 0;
    int constant endAt = 1 ether;
    bool public gameOver = false;
    event GameEnded(bool gameOver);
    event ScoreChanged(int amount,bool direction);

    function up() external payable {
        require(msg.value > 0);
        require(!gameOver);

        int value = int(msg.value);
        int amount= value;
        bool direction=true;
        score += value;

        //
        emit ScoreChanged(amount,direction);

        checkIfGameOver();
    }

    function down() external payable {
        require(msg.value > 0);
        require(!gameOver);

        int value = int(msg.value);
        int amount=value;
        bool direction=false;
        score -= value;

        //
        emit ScoreChanged(amount,direction);

        checkIfGameOver();
    }

    function checkIfGameOver() internal {
        if(score >= endAt || score <= endAt * -1) {
            gameOver = true;

            //
            emit GameEnded(gameOver);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

pragma solidity ^0.4.17;

contract TugOfWar {

```
int public score = 0;
int constant endAt = 1 ether;
bool public gameOver = false;
**event ScoreChanged (int amount, bool direction);
event GameEnded(bool gameOver);**

function up() external payable {
    require(msg.value > 0);
    require(!gameOver);

    int value = int(msg.value);
    score += value;
    **emit ScoreChanged(value, true);**

    //

    checkIfGameOver();
}

function down() external payable {
    require(msg.value > 0);
    require(!gameOver);

    int value = int(msg.value);
    score -= value;
    **emit ScoreChanged(value, false);**

    //

    checkIfGameOver();
}

function checkIfGameOver() internal {
    if(score >= endAt || score <= endAt * -1) {
        gameOver = true;
      
       **emit GameEnded(gameOver);**
        //
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Can you add an explanation how this solves the question?